# SAS SYSCC Macro Variable Behaviour

Tags: sas

It is my understanding that if a SAS process hits an error that the value of &SYSCC. will not be 0. which is the success return code. I am writing said variable to a text file to act as a go/no go signal to a Python script that I am using to orchestrate some wider processes.

Whilst testing the behaviour of said variable by triggering some simple, deliberate errors I have noticed that it is still returning zero:

```
%macro test;


sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs

%put &syscc. **********************************;

%mend;

%test;
```

Have I misunderstood something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a timing issue. No error has been generated at the point at which the %put statement executes.  The %test macro generates some text (sdsfsdfs..) and writes a valid `put` statement.  The semicolon *after* the macro invocation `;` creates a statement boundary (sdsfsdf...;) which *then* throws an error.

Order of execution:

1) compile macro

2) execute macro (`%test`)

3) execute `%put` statement

4) send `sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs` to input stack

5) finish executing macro

6) send final semicolon to input stack (`;`)

7)  `sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs;` is executed, which likely throws an error (it's too long to be a variable name but could be part of a valid `%let` statement);

Comment: yes i see that now, thanks. when i added a semi colon after my nonsense string SAS returned an error code of 3000...my test case for an error is unlikely to happen when my code gets to a batch state as finger trouble such as missing semi colons will have been ironed out whilst developing the code interactively...